# select and insert records as one xml field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables in 1:n relations and during an archive data storage I would like to store the n values into one xml field.
Tables:

- A(id, description, technology_id...)
- B(id, A.id, fieldname, value)

I have a table similar to A on the Archive schema that contains one additional XML type field, so Archive.A  has all dbo.A fields plus one. I understand that I can not make this in one step, so at first I move the records into the archive table A, then select connected values from dbo.B and insert them into the plus XML field with a FOR XML select.

The problem with this second step is that it dies with a message

> "illegal xml character"

but it doesn't help what is the character or how can I find it.

The update SQL query that throws error:

```
update aws set workstepdatas = 
    (select tdf.Fieldname Field, wsd.Value [Value] from dbo.worksteps ws
            left join workstepdatas wsd on wsd.WorkStep_Id = ws.id
            left join technologydatafields tdf on tdf.Id = wsd.TechnologyDatafields_Id
            where tdf.fieldname is not null and ws.id = aws.id
            for xml auto)
from archive.worksteps aws
inner join dbo.WorkStepDatas wsd on wsd.workstep_id = aws.id
where aws.id in (select id from @workstepIds);
```

If I run the select without the update with a where clause like `where ws.id in (select id from @workstepIds)` the query runs fine and gives proper xml records.

How can I get the illegal character? Why does it have an illegal character when I make the xml with sql server itself?

**Update:**

By the answer of @Shnugo I have a working one step query:

```
insert into archive.worksteps([Id], [Timestamp], [Description], [WorkPlace_Id], [WorkItemState_Id], [UserId], [WorkItem_Id], [Technology_Id], [Failcodes_Id], [DrawingNo], [ManualData], [Deleted], [WorkItemState_Arrival_Id], Workstepdatas)
    select [Id], [Timestamp], [Description], [WorkPlace_Id], [WorkItemState_Id], [UserId], [WorkItem_Id], [Technology_Id], [Failcodes_Id], [DrawingNo], [ManualData], [Deleted], [WorkItemState_Arrival_Id],
        (select tdf.Fieldname Field, wsd.Value [Value] from dbo.workstepdatas wsd
            left join dbo.technologydatafields tdf on tdf.Id = wsd.TechnologyDatafields_Id
            where tdf.fieldname is not null and wsd.WorkStep_Id = ws.Id
                and value NOT LIKE '%[' + CHAR(0)+ '-' +CHAR(31)+']%'  COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2
            for xml auto,type)
    from dbo.worksteps ws
    where ws.WorkItem_Id in (select Id from @workitemIds);
```

Comment: Just a quick shot: Try to append `, TYPE` after the `xml auto`. So, let it be `for xml auto, type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know, what you really try to achieve, but this works:

Some mockup tables

```
DECLARE @tblA TABLE(id INT IDENTITY, SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
DECLARE @tblB TABLE(id INT IDENTITY, aId INT, FieldName VARCHAR(100), FieldValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tblA VALUES('test 1'),('test 2');
INSERT INTO @tblB VALUES(1,'Field 1.1','Val 1.1.'),(1,'Field 1.2','Val 1.2')
                       ,(2,'Field 2.1','Val 2.1.'),(2,'Field 2.2','Val 2.2');
```

--The archive table

```
DECLARE @tblA_archive TABLE(id INT, SomeValue VARCHAR(100),bXML XML);
```

--This query will insert everything from `@tblA` and add all related `@tblB`-data as XML to the archive table **in one sinlge go**:

```
INSERT INTO @tblA_archive
SELECT a.id
      ,a.SomeValue
      ,(
        SELECT * FROM @tblB AS b 
        WHERE a.id=b.aId
        FOR XML AUTO,TYPE
       )
FROM @tblA AS a;
```

--The result

```
SELECT * FROM @tblA_archive;

id  SomeValue   bXML
1   test 1      <b id="1" aId="1" FieldName="Field 1.1" FieldValue="Val 1.1." /><b id="2" aId="1" FieldName="Field 1.2" FieldValue="Val 1.2" />
2   test 2      <b id="3" aId="2" FieldName="Field 2.1" FieldValue="Val 2.1." /><b id="4" aId="2" FieldName="Field 2.2" FieldValue="Val 2.2" />
```

Comment: I didn't think this can be done in one step, thanks.